# In .NET remoting, are both clientProvider and serverProvider required on the server side

Tags: .net, app-config, remoting

In many, many articles and samples online you see config files for the server side of a .NET remoting application like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.remoting>
   <application>
     <channels>
      <channel ref="http" port="9999">
        <serverProviders>
          <provider ref="wsdl" />
          <formatter ref="soap" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
          <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
        </serverProviders>
        <clientProviders>
         <formatter ref="binary" />
        </clientProviders>
      </channel>
     </channels>
     <service>
      <wellknown
        type="General.Shared, General"
        objectUri="Shared.soap"
        mode="Singleton"
        />
     </service>
   </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

Note that the client provider configuration info.  (Just one of the many samples found online).

**What purpose does any client-related remoting configuration serve on the server/service side?  Assuming the service uses no callbacks, is the client configuration needed at all?**

(Please note, this is in regards to debugging a legacy .NET 2.0 app that cannot be converted at this time to WCF.  For now I'm trying understand this aspect of the remoting setup).